# Как из текста создать PEM сертификат?

Tags: tomcat, ssl

Для HTTPS на Apache Tomcat 9 нашел инструкцию, в которой говорится, что нужно раскомментировать вот это:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                     certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                     certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Теперь, как я понимаю, нужно создать 3 файла **.pem** и поместить их в папку **conf**. У меня есть текст сертификата присланный на email

```
Ваш сертификат предоставлен ниже
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Корневой сертификат
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Промежуточный сертификат
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Запрос на получение сертификата
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
Сохраните приватный ключ на локальном компьютере.
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Какой текст куда копировать? В **localhost-rsa-key.pem** беру то что между BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY и END RSA PRIVATE KEY. А в другие 2 что копировать?

UPD

localhost-rsa-cert.pem надо копировать из первого пункта.

А вот chain переводится как "цепочка", поэтому скопировал в него весь текст как есть, но пока не вышло ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Вы уверены что там именно запрос на сертификат? Он  в этой цепочке не нужен, он используется для создания самого сертификата Центром Сертификации с данными из запроса сертификата.

Comment: @user3127286 я не понял вас. {Вы уверены что там именно запрос на сертификат?} где там?

Comment: кто прислал вам это письмо? если какие-нибудь комментарии в этом письме?

Comment: reg.ru "В письме содержатся данные, которые используются для установки SSL-сертификата на хостинг для вашего домена"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приватный ключ, используется в `certificateKeyFile`:

```
 -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ...
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

В `certificateFile` должен быть ваш конечный сертификат. Видимо, он первый в вашем списке.

`certificateChainFile` это файл [цепочки сертификатов](https://www.firstssl.ru/faq/ssl-installation/sozdanie-zepochki-ssl-sertifikatov). Он создается склеиванием всех сертификатов в одном файле. Т.е. в вашем случае должно быть что-то подобное:

```
Корневой сертификат
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Промежуточный(-е) сертификат(-ы)
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Ваш конечный серификат
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Грубо говоря, смысл цепочки сертификатов в том чтобы наложить какие-то ограничения на промежуточные сертификаты и, соответственно на их потомков.
Т.е. корневой сертификат чист, а промежуточные устанавливают свои наследуемые "детьми-сертификатами" правила.

Comment: я скопировал весь текст который мне пришел, с комментариями на русском, пока не помогло ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: кстати certificateKeyFile и certificateFile я копировал то что между begin и end без слов -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: нужно не весь текст, а то что я описал в ответе, без комментариев на русском

Comment: Приватный ключ нужно копировать только в таком формате  -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
   ...
 -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Запрос на получение сертификата тоже относится к промежуточным? то есть его тоже в CHAIN?

Comment: Запрос не нужен. Вам нужно внимательно прочитать мои комментарии, тогда все поймете.

Comment: последний пункт "Ваш конечный сертификат" это тот что первый в моём списке, который идет в certificateFile? и он обязательно должен быть в конце?

Comment: Да, верно. Он должен быть последним в списке.

Comment: Сайт отправил недействительный ответ.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: Вам, как минимум еще нужно описать поддерживаемые протоколы и шифры. Вполне может влиять опция UpgradeProtocol, попробуйте ее убрать. Посмотрите доки: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/ssl-howto.html. А лучше всего в техподдержку напишите.

Comment: Все работает, порт старый писал 8080 вместо 8443. Спасибо!